# How to find string before and after specified word using Grep and RegEx

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

For Example I have a files that contains the ff set of strings

```
AAA1111BBB -> FILE1
AAA2222BBB -> FILE2
AAA3333BBB -> FILE3
```

Now in unix, I want to extract all IDs by searching the pattern of AAA as start of the line and BBB as the end of the pattern. Output will something like this

```
1111
2222
3333
```

Then I want to remove all duplicate entries then save it in a file. How will I able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `grep -P` option available you can try

```
(?<=A{3})\d+(?=B{3})
```

this regex which uses lookarounds to find the digits surrounded by `AAA` and `BBB`

Comment: what if i have a sample file that contains AAAZ1@6BBB?

Comment: Then change `\d+` to `.+?`

Comment: Also, use `grep -o -P pattern` to emit just the matches

Comment: @PeterS use `.*?` in place of `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your little example could be accomplished with this command:

```
sed -e 's/^AAA//' -e 's/BBB.*//' input.txt | sort -u > output.txt
```

But, my guess is that your toy example may not sufficiently explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    match($1, /^AAA(.*)BBB$/, m) {keys[m[1]]=1}
    END {for (k in keys) print k}
' file
```

or perl

```
perl -nE '/^AAA(\w+)BBB/ and $k{$1}=1 }END{ say join "\n", keys %k' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your IDs are 4 digit numbers:

```
grep -oE "AAA[0-9]{4}BBB" <filename> | grep -oE "[0-9]{4}"
```

Edit:

If you have something like "AAA12@3BBB" :

```
 grep -oE "AAA.{4}BBB" <filename> | grep -oE "[0-9,@]{4}"
```